# What does 'ambient' in this scenario?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> Ambient: relating to the immediate surroundings of something.
>   "the liquid is stored at below ambient temperature".

Cited from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ambient).

As far as I know 'ambient' is an adjective that refers to the surrounding, e.g. ambient lighting of the room gave rise to a gloomy mood ; ambient temperature/sounds etc. So what does ambient mean in the dictionary's example sentence?

Comment: Hi @Specter. I've edited for formatting and added a link. You can roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @AndyT the sentence is within the yellow citation box right after the meaning.

Comment: @Pam much appreciated, I tried but couldn't form paragraphs :).

Comment: @Specter, it's a double carriage return. Actually, you've probably learned quite a bit from the edits you've seen...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's clearer if we read "is stored" as meaning "*should be* stored", as in "is [normally] stored [if treated correctly]".

So here 'ambient' really means **'room temperature'**, which in a scientific context normally means somewhere between 20 to 25°C. Or, if the context is an environment where the 'normal' (*ambient*) temperature is something else, this is saying that the liquid should be stored below *that*.

(Of course, an obvious way that you can store something below room temperature is to put it in a refrigerator so that it adopts the (cold) temperature of that place, which is *its* ambient temperature...!)

Comment: So 'ambient' here is used in a sense subjective to humans in the context?  So hypothetically speaking , if I were to be placed in a freezer the 'ambient temeprature' would be cold ?

Comment: Exactly! The dictionary example you quoted is, in my opinion, quite a bad one, because the term ambient is intrinsically relative to its context...but there was no context given in the example. However, as you've correctly guessed, the context is so often human that you can generally presume 'ambient' without any other context defaults to that. And yes, for example, as a quick Google search revealed: "the annual average ambient temperature in the Arctic region is close to 0°C".

Comment: I had the same thought when I first saw the sentence. These sample sentences are proving to be more often , misleading than benefical in helping me comprhened the meanings of the words. Thanks for helping me disslove the skepticism ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ambient literally means ‘what is around’.

Etymology - Ambient:

late 16th century: from French ambiant or Latin ambient- ‘going around,’ from ambire.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=etymology+ambient&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

‘Below ambient temperature’ means ‘below the temperature of ‘what is around’ - ie - below room temperature. If the item is ‘in a room’.

If you put something in a fridge, it will take on the surrounding temperature ‘ambient temperature’ of the fridge.

Ambient is ‘what is around’.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence "the liquid is stored at below ambient temperature", *ambient* takes its normal meaning: the surroundings.

If the temperature in my house is 20<sup>o</sup>C, and I store some milk in my fridge at 4<sup>o</sup>C, then the "ambient" temperature can be understood as the room temperature, rather than the temperature within the fridge, and hence the milk is stored at below ambient temperature.

Similarly if the temperature outside varies between -5<sup>o</sup>C and +35<sup>o</sup>C, with a refrigerated warehouse kept at -20<sup>o</sup>C, then anything stored within that warehouse is stored at below ambient temperature.

Comment: so ambient can mean 'normal' (from an anthropic prespective) as well as 'surrounding' ?

Comment: Don’t think about “anthropic perspective” think “what would be the normal steady-state temperature without any interference”